# Bash script to kill screens with the same name

Tags: bash, kill

So I have a system that has multiple screens running at the same time, a list like:

```
    2606.molamola19 (Detached)
    13481.johnappy1 (Detached)
    26017.Dylkill   (Detached)
    17061.legoman993        (Detached)
    15984.legoman993        (Detached)
    7418.taytotayto (Detached)
    7336.wpgradford (Detached)
    11913.twbone    (Detached)
    31947.1christiant       (Detached)
    20124.legoman993        (Detached)
    15034.PWNman567 (Detached)
    13119.johnappy1 (Detached)
    21084.legoman993        (Detached)
    9294.Ncraven00  (Detached)
    17200.A_Naked_Equinox   (Detached)
    4331.somegreatvids999   (Detached)
    18849.Djfireblade       (Detached)
    1104.AlfieW5    (Detached)
    7926.superhoi   (Detached)
    27904.ty281998123a      (Detached)
    14870.johnappy1 (Detached)
    4340.stapler12  (Detached)
    21244.oas510    (Detached)
    21032.jaater    (Detached)
    14320.johnappy1 (Detached)
    15188.sammyboy40        (Detached)
```

Because of connection problems to the clients, sometimes multiple instancs of the same screen get started such as:

```
    14320.johnappy1 (Detached)
    14870.johnappy1 (Detached)
```

I've been trying to learn Bash the past couple of days to figure out how to kill any process that has a more than 1 (when a second one is created or a third, etc, it ruins the first instance anyways)

Any help would be amazingly appreciative!

The output that I showed was generated with screen -r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: added Explanation and changed command (see comment of
Jeremy Sayers)

It's been a long time since I used screen, but I think i can still give you the right hint.
First filter out those instances, you want to kill, then kill them:

```
screen -r | \
  sort -t. -k2,2 -k1,1 | \
  awk 'BEGIN { i=""; FS = "([[:space:]]|\\.)+" };{if($2 == i) print $1; i = $2;}' | \
  while read x; do kill -9 $x; done
```

Explanation:

```
sort -t. -k2,2 -k1,1
```

sorts first after the name (e.g. johnappy1) and then after the
PID (since I assume you want to keep the first instance started).

```
awk 'BEGIN { i=""; FS = "([[:space:]]|\\.)+" };{if($2 == i) print $1; i = $2;}'
```

Will filter out all multiple instances and output the higher PIDs
of them (ommiting only the first, lowest PID).

```
while read x; do kill -9 $x; done
```

will loop through all PIDs we got from the previous command and
will invoke "kill -9" on them.

Comment: Normally I kille them with kill -9 pid, as in the pid that is infront of their name, using your script how would I grab the pid?

Comment: I tried running it, but no processes were killed, what would I do to make it echo what pid it was trying to kill? would I just put echo infront of kill -9 $x?

Comment: To see what PIDs are emitted just omit the last line (the while loop). I tried it with your example and got 13481
14320
14870
17061
20124
21084. Try also to omit the last two lines to see the sorted output.